# Syntax error: Unexpected token error

Tags: javascript

Am getting a syntax error here, but can't understand why. TIA

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
console.log(computerChoice);

if(computerChoice >= 0.33) {
    computerChoice === "rock";
} else if ( computerChoice >= 0.34 && <= 0.66){
    computerChoice === "paper";
} else (computerChoice >= 0.67 && <= 1) {
    computerChoice === "scissors";
}
```

Comment: What is the error ...And what does the console log say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, there are a couple of issues here.

Syntactically:

```
} else ( computerChoice >= 0.67 && <= 1 ) {
```

should be

```
} else if ( computerChoice >= 0.67 && computerChoice <= 1 ) {
```

or

```
} else {
```

but the stuff that is executed in your conditional blocks doesn't actually do anything. You are just testing some stuff for equality and then ignoring the results of the test.

I imagine what you were going for is closer to:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
console.log(computerChoice);

if ( computerChoice <= 0.33 ) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if ( computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice <= 0.66 ) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a variable name (`computerChoice`) for your second logical comparison and an `else` instead of `elseif` in the last part of the code. Additionally you are using a type/value comparison at points where you should have been using assignment.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
console.log(computerChoice);

if(computerChoice >= 0.33) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if ( computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice <= 0.66){
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
```

Comment: You are still using comparison instead of assignment.

Comment: Something is going on with SO the whole day as it seems to keep only select edits :/ Thanks, corrected the code.